# Java Script, values not assign to variable

Tags: javascript

I am a novice in Java Script and I do not quite understand why variable `action` does not have any assigned value, even though I thought I have assigned it:

```
var prompt = require('sync-prompt').prompt;

var add = function(a, b){
    return a + b;
};
var minus = function(a, b){
    return a + b;
};
var multiply = function(a, b){
    return a + b;
};

var chooseAction = function(znak) {
  var action;

  switch(znak) {
    case "+":
        action = add;
        break;
    case "-":
        action = minus;
        break;
    case "*":
        action = multiply;
        break;
  }
  return action;
}

var compute = function() {
  var input = prompt("Wpisz działanie ");
  var arguments = input.split(' ');
  var a = parseInt(arguments[0]);
  var b = parseInt(arguments[2]);
  var action = chooseAction(arguments[1]);
  console.log("Wynik działania: " + action(a, b));
}

compute();
```

Comment: you are adding in all functions, correct it

Comment: and use callback, check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTbSfCT42_M)

Comment: you need to change the operator according to the function's name

Comment: check input, does it look same like this > '2 + 3'

Answer (score 3):

Beside the wrong operator of the function, I suggest not to use a reserved local variable of a function with the name [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Another point, for using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), I suggest to use the `radix` parameter as well, if you have numbers with leading zero, it could be treated as octal numbers.

```js
var add = function(a, b){
    return a + b;
};
var minus = function(a, b){
    return a - b;
};
var multiply = function(a, b){
    return a * b;
};

var chooseAction = function(znak) {
  var action;

  switch(znak) {
    case "+":
        action = add;
        break;
    case "-":
        action = minus;
        break;
    case "*":
        action = multiply;
        break;
  }
  return action;
}

var compute = function() {
  var input = prompt("Wpisz działanie ");
  var args = input.split(' ');
  var a = parseInt(args[0], 10); // use radix
  var b = parseInt(args[2], 10); // use radix
  var action = chooseAction(args[1]);
  console.log("Wynik działania: " + action(a, b));
}

compute();
```

Comment: the same result despite different operators?

Comment: The operator issue was present. But the question says "why variable action do not have assigned value". This can imply the action variable has no value at all. Maybe the question is incomplete

Comment: it can be an issue  if you pass something like this in prompt ==> 3+4 without any space, split will fail then.

Comment: right, but splitting is based upon space, please ask the op for that.

Answer (score -1):

The function `require` in your code is not defined. Therefore an error occurs when you try to set a value for the `prompt` variable. You have to add `require` function and it will works!

Comment: [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is a module loader, I'm sure they're including a reference to that script somewhere else on their page, if you're not sure, add a comment asking if they've done so.

Comment: RequireJS is what specifies the `require` function.

Comment: @George, are you sure what the `require.js` is included to OP's project?